# Etale Stalks of the Hom sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I am reading Milne's lectures on etale cohomology. In the note he states:

Proposition 6.16 Assume $X$ is connected, and let $\bar{x}$ be a geometric point of $X$. The map $\mathcal{F} \mapsto \mathcal{F}_{\bar{x}}$ defines an equivalence between the category of locally constant sheaves of sets (resp. abelian groups) with finite stalks on $X$ and the category of finite $\pi_1(X, \bar{x})$-sets (resp. modules).

PROOF. In fact, one shows that, if $Z \rightarrow X$ is a finite étale map, then the sheaf $\mathcal{F}_Z$ is locally constant with finite stalks, and every such sheaf is of this form for some $Z$; more precisely, $Z \mapsto \mathcal{F}_Z$ defines an equivalence from FEt/ $X$ to the category of locally constant sheaves on $X_{\text {et }}$ with finite stalks. Now we can apply Theorem 3.1 to prove the proposition.

Where the sheaf is : An $X$-scheme $Z$ defines a contravariant functor:
$$
\mathcal{F}: \text { Et } / X \rightarrow \text { Sets, } \quad \mathcal{F}(U)=\operatorname{Hom}_X(U, Z) .
$$

Does he mean that the etale stalks of the sheaf is $\operatorname{Hom}_X(\bar{x}, Z)$? Because the theorem states

Define $F:$ FEt $/ X \rightarrow$ Sets to be the functor sending $(Y, \pi)$ to the set of $\bar{x}$-valued points of $Y$ lying over $x$, so $F(Y)=\operatorname{Hom}_X(\bar{x}, Y)$.

THEOREM 3.1 The functor $Y \mapsto F(Y)$ defines an equivalence from the category of finite étale coverings of $X$ to the category of finite discrete $\pi_1(X, \bar{x})$-sets.

I don't see why this should be ture.

Comment: I don’t quite understand your question… Are you asking whether the stalk at $\overline{x}$ of $\mathrm{Hom}_X(-,Z)$ is $\mathrm{Hom}_X(\overline{x},Z)$? (This isn’t a tautology since $\overline{x}$ is probably not finite étale over $X$).

Comment: @Aphelli Yes. Since this makes a commutative diagram with two equivalences and hence the third one, taking stalks, will be a equivalence of category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to prove.

Suppose we have two $X$-maps $f_i: U_i \rightarrow Z$ with $X$-maps $x_i: \overline{x} \rightarrow U_i$ such that $f_1 \circ x_1=f_2 \circ x_2$.

Then we have a map $(f_1,f_2): U_1 \times_X U_2 \rightarrow Z \times_X Z$, and the inverse image $W$ of the diagonal is an open subscheme of $U_1 \times_X U_2$ (hence is étale over $X$) and “contains” $(x_1,x_2)$. In particular, it’s non-empty, so that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the same on the stalk of $\overline{x}$.

It follows that $\operatorname{Hom}_X(-,Z)_{\overline{x}} \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_X(\overline{x},Z)$ is injective.

To show that it is surjective, one needs to show that any map $\overline{x} \rightarrow Z$ extends to some $g: U \rightarrow Z$, for some $h: \overline{x} \rightarrow U$.

Take $U=Z$ and $g=\mathrm{id}$, $h$ being the given map $\overline{x} \rightarrow Z$.